# CUDA samples not compiling due to multiple redefinition errors

Tags: c++, macos, cuda

I just installed CUDA toolkit 7.5 on OSX 10.11 with Xcode 7. Macbook Pro with GeForce GT 750M

When compiling (make) the samples I get multiple redefinition errors. Here are the first two:

[actual console output (partial)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ04A.png)

error sample:

> In file included from tmpxft_0000b964_00000000-19_asyncAPI.compute_20.cudafe1.stub.c:1:
>   In file included from /var/folders/bm/fp5n2kzd419c4mbnsmyqf1cm0000gn/T/tmpxft_0000b964_00000000-19_asyncAPI.compute_20.cudafe1.stub.c:7:
>   In file included from /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:247:
>   In file included from /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include/common_functions.h:224:
>   In file included from /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include/math_functions.h:10219:
>   In file included from /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.5/bin/../include/math_functions.hpp:1664:
>   /usr/include/math.h:204:48: error: redefinition of '**inline_isfinitef'
>   inline __attribute** ((**always_inline**)) int **inline_isfinitef(float __x) {
>                                                  ^
>   /usr/include/math.h:204:58: note: previous definition is here
>   extern "C" { __attribute((__always_inline**)) inline int __inline_isfinitef(float __x)

The errors are related to math.h includes. Interestingly some of the samples if compiled manually such as the deviceQuery sample do compile and run.

Custom code that I have written also fails with the same errors. In my code if I comment out the "math.h" and the  include the errors are the same. I do include NVIDIA's cutil_math.h

I've tried changing the clang version down to 6.4 but it makes no difference. I've also tried multiple compiler flags to no avail.

Comment: According to the [Getting Started document for Mac](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html) CUDA 7.5 supports Mac OS X versions 10.9 and 10.10. So you are on an unsupported platform. The incompatibilities between header files you are observing are exactly the kind of issues that require NVIDIA to continuously adjust their toolchain and the header files needed for tight host-compiler integration, which in turn is necessary to allow mixing host and device code in the same file. You might want to check whether the OS X toolchain lets you suppress these errors.

Comment: @njuffa while the table in the link you provided omits 10.11 in the list, to be fair the download for the 7.5 Toolkit has an explicit option for 10.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide a solution that will fix the problem, but might cause a problem in the future.

The error is showing the sequence of includes down to where the problem is occuring. In this case `7.5/bin/../include/math_functions.hpp:1664`

On line 1664 of math_functions.hpp comment out `#include "math.h"` and `#include <cmath>` below it. This will remove the redefinition and your project will no longer have this error, and the samples will compile.