# Redefinitions when compiling CUDA with clang on Windows

Tags: c++, cuda, clang++

Despite an almost identical [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365745/cuda-samples-not-compiling-due-to-multiple-redefinition-errors) already asked, the answer is for OSX and no longer holds true (and is really hacky anyways).

The problem is when compiling cuda with clang on windows, there is tonnes of redefinitions in `math_functions.hpp`.

With some investigations, apparently cuda decided to put its `math_functions.hpp` and `math_functions.h` functions in `namespace std` (is this even legal?), and collided with all the libstdc++ functions in `cmath` and clang's own headers for compiling cuda.

How do I deal with this? Preferably not with the hacky way shown in the previous question?

#### Side note

According to clang's [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/CompileCudaWithLLVM.html#overloading-based-on-host-and-device-attributes), clang can overload based on `__global__`/`__device__` qualifiers, shouldn't the code just compile anyways?

#### Details

Versions:
clang 4.0.0 (built like [this](https://here-be-braces.com/blog/building-clang-natively-on-windows-mingw))
libstdc++ came from gcc 7.1.0
cuda 8.0
windows 10

Full error output

```
clang++ hellocuda.cu  --cuda-path=E:\cuda\development --cuda-gpu-arch=sm_20 -LE:\cuda\development\lib\x64 -lcudart_static -ldl -lrt -std=c++1y -O2 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -fms-extensions -o program.exe
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:191:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:1684:14: error: redefinition of
      '__isnan'
__func__(int __isnan(double a))
             ^
E:\TDM-GCC\mingw64 7.1.0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\math.h:525:28: note:
      previous definition is here
  __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __isnan (double _x)
                           ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:191:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:1764:14: error: redefinition of
      '__signbit'
__func__(int __signbit(double a))
             ^
E:\TDM-GCC\mingw64 7.1.0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\math.h:611:28: note:
      previous definition is here
  __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __signbit (double x) {
                           ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:191:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:1776:17: error: redefinition of
      'copysign'
__func__(double copysign(double a, double b))
                ^
E:\TDM-GCC\mingw64 7.1.0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\math.h:1069:31: note:
      previous definition is here
  __CRT_INLINE double __cdecl copysign (double x, double y)
                              ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:191:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:3161:14: error: redefinition of
      '__signbitl'
__func__(int __signbitl(long double a))
             ^
E:\TDM-GCC\mingw64 7.1.0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\math.h:636:28: note:
      previous definition is here
  __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __signbitl (long double x) {
                           ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:191:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:3166:14: error: redefinition of
      '__signbitf'
__func__(int __signbitf(float a))
             ^
E:\TDM-GCC\mingw64 7.1.0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\math.h:624:28: note:
      previous definition is here
  __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __signbitf (float x) {
                           ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:191:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:3191:14: error: redefinition of
      '__isnanl'
__func__(int __isnanl(long double a))
             ^
E:\TDM-GCC\mingw64 7.1.0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\math.h:565:28: note:
      previous definition is here
  __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __isnanl (long double _x)
                           ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:191:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:3196:14: error: redefinition of
      '__isnanf'
__func__(int __isnanf(float a))
             ^
E:\TDM-GCC\mingw64 7.1.0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\math.h:546:28: note:
      previous definition is here
  __CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __isnanf (float _x)
                           ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:191:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:3360:16: error: redefinition of
      'copysignf'
__func__(float copysignf(float a, float b))
               ^
E:\TDM-GCC\mingw64 7.1.0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\math.h:1076:30: note:
      previous definition is here
  __CRT_INLINE float __cdecl copysignf (float x, float y)
                             ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:250:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:365:43: error: functions that differ
      only in their return type cannot be overloaded
static __inline__ __host__ __device__ int isinf(double a)
                                      ~~~ ^
E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_math_forward_declares.h:107:17: note:
      previous declaration is here
__DEVICE__ bool isinf(double);
           ~~~~ ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:250:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:381:43: error: functions that differ
      only in their return type cannot be overloaded
static __inline__ __host__ __device__ int isinf(float a)
                                      ~~~ ^
E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_math_forward_declares.h:108:17: note:
      previous declaration is here
__DEVICE__ bool isinf(float);
           ~~~~ ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:250:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:413:43: error: functions that differ
      only in their return type cannot be overloaded
static __inline__ __host__ __device__ int isnan(double a)
                                      ~~~ ^
E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_math_forward_declares.h:115:17: note:
      previous declaration is here
__DEVICE__ bool isnan(double);
           ~~~~ ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:250:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:429:43: error: functions that differ
      only in their return type cannot be overloaded
static __inline__ __host__ __device__ int isnan(float a)
                                      ~~~ ^
E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_math_forward_declares.h:116:17: note:
      previous declaration is here
__DEVICE__ bool isnan(float);
           ~~~~ ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:250:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:461:43: error: functions that differ
      only in their return type cannot be overloaded
static __inline__ __host__ __device__ int isfinite(double a)
                                      ~~~ ^
E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_math_forward_declares.h:101:17: note:
      previous declaration is here
__DEVICE__ bool isfinite(double);
           ~~~~ ^
In file included from <built-in>:1:
In file included from E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h:250:
E:\cuda\development/include\math_functions.hpp:477:43: error: functions that differ
      only in their return type cannot be overloaded
static __inline__ __host__ __device__ int isfinite(float a)
                                      ~~~ ^
E:\LLVM\bin\..\lib\clang\4.0.0\include\__clang_cuda_math_forward_declares.h:102:17: note:
      previous declaration is here
__DEVICE__ bool isfinite(float);
           ~~~~ ^
14 errors generated.
makefile:15: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: +1 for trying to compile CUDA code with clang. Whoever answers - putting your answer in context of using clang with CUDA more generally would be well-appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to use an older version of libstdc++ or even [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/BuildingLibcxx.html)?

Comment: @jlk clang's own headers for compiling cuda collides with cuda's headers, so switching libraries won't help with that. I'll try libc++ and see if those `cmath` goes away though

Comment: @PasserBy The conflict is between libstdc++'s math.h and CUDA's math_functions.hpp, clang only tries to avoid the conflicts by doing a lot of black magic in __clang_cuda_runtime_wrapper.h so it's possible that something changed in the recent versions of MinGW's libstdc++. Clang's docs say that compiling CUDA on Windows is supported as of 2017-01-05, so I assume that was working at some point. Note that on Linux the functions like __isnan are not defined in the standard library and in the CUDA header they are guarded by `#if defined(_WIN32)`, so the problem might be just due to lack of testing.

Comment: You try to compile CUDA definitions with Clang. This causes collisions with pre-existing macro definitions. As macros are scopeless, it may help to un-define them.

Comment: @jlk I flipped through MinGW's math.h. They do have __isnan defined, even back in 4.9.2. It is used as a dispatch target for isnan with some complicated macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried quite a bit of stuff. They failed. In the end I dug into the headers and literally macroed out anything that has a conflict, which are located in

- cuda's math_functions.hpp
- clang's __clang_cuda_math_forward_declares.h
- clang's __clang_cuda_cmath.h

clang uses `_MSC_VER` to detect Windows, which is defined only if -fms-compatibility flag is used, but this causes a ton of other errors elsewhere for unknown reasons.

cuda uses a mixture of `_WIN32` and `_MSC_VER` to detect Windows. As far as I can tell, just macroing away everything that is a redefinition is simply the easiest way to do this.

This seems to be working, as in no other header errors popped up.